# Web.Contents() with username, password and domain

Tags: powerquery

I'm using the following mcode to get data from the web

```
Source = Web.Contents(url,[Headers=[Authorization="Bearer " & XXX],Timeout=#duration(0, 0, 0 ,1),IsRetry=false])
```

However, XXX needs to log in to the web and then go to the DEV tool to get it

Is there a way to use web.contents with username, password and domain instead of the above method?

I tried

```
Source = Web.Contents(url,[RelativePath = "restapi/v1/token?" & "username=xxx" & "&password=xxx" & "domain=xxx"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Web.Contents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/web-contents) like this:

```
Source = Web.Contents(
    url,
    [
        RelativePath = "restapi/v1/token", 
        Query = 
        [
            username = "xxx",
            password = "yyy"
            domain = "zzz"
        ],
        Timeout = #duration(0, 0, 0 ,1),
        IsRetry = false
    ]
)
```